# SQL Service Broker: Collecting data -- plug-in scenario analysis

Tags: sql, sql-server, service-broker

(**2nd Update from 2012/12/06** -- new protocol, a sligtly different view)

The question is whether the solution below seems reasonable for you, or whether there is any flaw that I did not notice (being quite new to SQL Server Service Broker)...

I would like to continue in analysis of the problem presented in the [SQL Service Broker: Collecting data from distributed sources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12446912/1346705). I would like to focus on the problem of protocol to be used when collecting data from the satellite SQL servers. The usage of the SQL Server Service Broker is a must -- it is dictated also by other reasons not presented here. So, please, do not suggest completely alternative solutions.

I would like to focus on details of what should be done and how to use the Service Broker naturally (the best possible way) for the exact problem. The overall goal [was presented in the above mentioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12446912/1346705). The picture first:

[image: Sensor data from production line are collected to the centralized table.]
Now more details to be considered...

**Plug-in architecture wanted**

The satellite machines are related to real physical production lines. It can happen that some machine is added to the technology process, some machine can disappear, some machine can be replaced in the sense it will use the same production-line identification, but it is physically different -- i.e. its SQL server is a different instance.

The central server knows nothing about the satellite until it gets first messages from it. There is no centralized database of the satelite servers. No knowledge about what and how many satelite SQL servers are to be included to the system. It is always decided on the satelite site.

Any activity related to collecting the data should be initiated by events generated by the satellite machines.

**Important:** The goal is to continually transfer all the newly created data (from sensors), and to discover and fix drop-outs -- independently on whatever could cause them.

To give you the concrete example:

1. The machine identified by line number 3 (yellow) was recently added to the environment. Its SQL Server Express was launched and it started to collect the sensor data (the third party solution, dedicated table with special structure). The machine was not connected to the central server, yet.
2. The only configuration thing is the reliably assigned fixed identification of the production line (here 3), and all the neccessary details to connect to the central SQL server. But the central SQL server does not know the information. The central is just ready to accept data from any new souce, but never knows when. (It was already tested for one machine [using the approach suggested by Remus Rusanu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11704632/1346705) to the question [SQL Service Broker — one central SQL and more satelite SQL…](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11692754/1346705).)
3. The piece of the SQL software is deployed on the machine 3 just a bit later. It starts to talk with the central. The satellite part is not dumb, but its own activity is to send the sensor data whenever new record is inserted to the sensor data table (see point 1 above). From the record, UTC time is calculated (from the proprietary format), several sensor data from one record is converted to the same number of normalized records (formatted as one XML message), and sent to the central SQL server.
4. The central is activated by the message with the sensor data sent from the satellite machine. The failures of the physical connection is masked by the Service Broker queues.
5. After a reasonable interval (here one hour), the central server checks whether the so far collected data should be processed or not. There is a work unit that takes some production time, and the data should be processed and added to the documentation of the unit. The processing should happen only when the unit was finished.
6. The central also checks whether it has all the data for the unit. As the sensor sampling is done in known regular intervals (here about 1 minute), the central can check whether there are some **drop-outs**. There also is an initial "drop-out" for the time interval when the satellite was not connected to the central via SSB. The mechanism should recover from whatever situation. It can also happen that the sensor where out of order or the data were not collected. The detected drop-out at the central may actually mean that central asks: *"I have no data from you for this time interval. Send me some of them if they exist, or tell me they do not exist."*
7. The satellite should send only that much data that can be sent between the sampling times. The recovery from drop-outs can be rather slow. The delay of processing the data at the central server is not critical. However, the central should know when the data is ready (or does not exist for the detected time interval).

**Some picture, more solution details**

[image: Time diagram of communication between the satellite and central server.]

I have chosen the ["Recycling conversations" by Remus Rusanu](http://rusanu.com/2007/05/03/recycling-conversations/) as the basic framework for the communication between the satellite and the central. It defines the `EndOfStream` message type to signal that the conversation handle should be thrown away and the new one should be used. The lifetime is limited by the above mentioned one hour interval generated by the Service Broker timer.

The message is (mis)used at the central server also for activation of the data processing. At about the same time, the central checks for drop-outs. The central keeps the time below that the drop-outs where already checked. This way it knows what data are ready to be processed.

Do you consider the scenario reasonable? Can you see any problem with it?

(I am going to refine the question to reflect your suggestions.)

Thanks for your time and experience, and have a nice day.

Petr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. All data should be stored in table. On satellite side, you should create a table for last processed row to be stored. When new request from Central arrives, new data pack will be sent back to Central depending on last processed record value.
   Note: i recommend to limit a number of rows to be sent depending on your data to do not create very large data packs.
2. When Central processed all rows, appropriate message should be sent to Satellite. It also should contain information about data import errors occurred.
3. You can start Service Broker conversation when database activity is registered (using DML/DDL triggers on both Central/Satellite database) or within schedule (using Central Agent job).