# SQL Service Broker - communication scenario - migration from SQL 2008 R2 to SQL 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, service-broker

**Summary:** Is there anything new in SQL Server 2014 (versus 2008 R2) that does not allow the following scenario? Can the same approach be transfered to the new server?

The application uses SQL Service Broker to collect data from satellite SQL Express machines (technology computers, now two, soon 4, and possibly more) to the central SQL Server with SQL Server Standard edition.

It is based on simplified security settings without the need to exchange certificates. I was asked to migrate the solution from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014.

The situation was described in details at [SQL Service Broker -- one central SQL and more satelite SQL... beginner wants to understand details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11692754/1346705) and the solution was based on the [Remus Rusanu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11704632/1346705).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. All SQL Server releases, from 2005 to 2014 inclusive, are [compatible with each other at the Service Broker](http://rusanu.com/2007/11/28/is-service-broker-in-sql-server-2008-compatible-with-the-one-in-sql-server-2005/) layer. In fact the 2008 instances are not even going to be able to figure out they are talking to 2014.

You should be able to migrate one machine at a time, w/o taking down everything. If the upgrades are don in-place (keeping the machine name the same and preserving the SSB endpoint settings) then you won't have to change anything after the upgrade, it should just keep working.

If you do side-by-side upgrade then you will have to port the SSB endpoint settings and certificates used from one instance to the other, along with moving the database.

Keep in mind that if you have a problem and you are forced to rollback to a backup then your entire, distributed, system state will not be consistent (basically conversations will no longer match the send sequence number and receive sequence numbers) and you may have to force some close conversations (manual END ... WITH CLEANUP on a case by case) or nuke the entire broker in the DB (ALTER DATABASE ... SET NEW_BROKER). Lets hope you won't have to do this. If is feasible then you could simply stop the entire system (eg. run ALTER ENDPOINT ... STATE = STOPPED on all 3 nodes to stop all SSB communication) and then do a backup and then do the upgrade, now being safe to rollback the upgrade and restore since everythign is 'frozen'.

Comment: Actually, the situation that would require stopping the mechanism is not critical for me. If needed, I have scripts (generated from templates) to stop sending the data, to uninstall everything, and install it again. Anyway, I will study the ALTER ENDPOINT for stopping the conversation. One problem is that the messages are sent via trigger. If the mechanism stops, I will not get the older sensor data. And it happened just these days.

Comment: No, if you stop the endpoint triggers can continue to send. Triggers can happily issue SEND, it will work. Data will accumulate in `sys.transmission_queue`. When you resume communication the transmission queue will drain and all data accumulated will be sent. You just have to be sure that the accumulated data does not exceed the Express 10GB limit. I had once a system stay offline for 42 days (bad network config), and then it resumed and transmitted everything pending.

Comment: I have met a problem after migration. The target SQL gets the data, and they are collected in the queue. However, the attached procedure is not activated. Please, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/31825844/1346705