# SQL Server 2014 Service Broker does not activate the procedure that receives messages from the queue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, service-broker

The situation is closely related to [SQL Service Broker - communication scenario - migration from SQL 2008 R2 to SQL 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28982099/1346705) and to [SQL Service Broker -- one central SQL and more satelite SQL... beginner wants to understand details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11692754/1346705).

After migration from SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Ed. to SQL Server 2014 Standard Ed., the same code does not work. The firewall was set to allow the communication.

The `sys.transmission_queue` (on both sender and receiver servers) keeps empty, and the `GenericQueue` (my identifier for the queue) receives the messages. However, the procedure attached by (to the receiving SQL server):

```
ALTER QUEUE [GenericQueue]
    WITH ACTIVATION (
    STATUS = ON,
    MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1,
    PROCEDURE_NAME = [usp_CentralActivation],
    EXECUTE AS OWNER);
```

is not activated. I have put the log message inside to have the tangible proof -- the procedure is not called.

I do not observe any error message or indication -- or I do not know where to look for the indication. How can I find what is the problem? What information should I post here to help to find the reason?

The code that installs the service broker is generated from templates, and besides the machine identification (IP address as a string) the exact same code worked nicely on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Could the `EXECUTE AS OWNER` be the reason? Who is the `OWNER`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A shot in the dark. Try running this:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'dbo';
```

If this fails, then the database owner SID is invalid locally (happens frequently after a restore or file copy). The solution is trivial:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<dbname> TO [sa];
```

If you still have problems then have a look at [Understanding Queue Monitors](http://rusanu.com/2008/08/03/understanding-queue-monitors/). Look in `sys.dm_broker_queue_monitors` and see that 1) the queue is present and 2) the status is RECEIVES_OCCURING

Comment: This was the very precise shot in the dark, indeed. Thanks a lot!